# Getting error while producing data with alias name from schema using confluent .Net package

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

My avro schema is having field name as orderId and its aliases are "emp_order_id", "emp_order_no"

Field in AVRO schema
{ "name": "orderId", "aliases": ["emp_order_id", "emp_order_no"], "type": "string", "doc": "emp order " },

Now I am trying to produce below message using confluent .Net library (c# code) to Kafka topic with alias name "emp_order_id" , But getting error stating that -
Error - InnerException = {"System.String required to write against String schema but found null in field orderId"}

As we already have alias for orderId field so ideally it should produce right or is there any configuration or code change require to support same ?
JSON data for above avro -
"emp_order_id": "req00062nk27"

Comment: Seems like your error is with the c# Avro implementation, not Kafka or the Registry

Comment: ok so could you share some sample how alias name from schema can be used to produce message ?